# undeclared identifier error with correct include and declaration

Tags: c++, compilation, include, declaration

I'm creating an application in Qt
i get a compilation error: error C2065: 'callDialog' : undeclared identifier
in my CategoryDialog class
error line:

```
CallDialog* callDialog = ((CallDialog*)dialogStack->widget(1));
```

5th last line in CategoryDialog class:

```
    #include "ui_categorydialog_new.h"
    #include "calldialog.h"
    #include "questionsdialog.h"
    #include "../objects/call.h"
    #include "../webservice/dataconnector.h"
    #include "../webservice/dataconngetter.h"

    namespace Ui {
        class CategoryDialog;
    }

    class CategoryDialog : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit CategoryDialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::CategoryDialog){
            ui->setupUi(this);
        }

        ~CategoryDialog()
        {
            delete ui;
        }

    private slots:
        void on_btn_back_clicked()
        {
            ui->btn_back->setEnabled(false);
            DataConnGetter::getConnector()->setCallAbort(call->getId()); //get errormessage back and show errormessage when nessesary
            QStackedWidget* dialogStack = (QStackedWidget*)this->parentWidget();
            CallDialog* callDialog = ((CallDialog*)dialogStack->widget(1)); //TODO 005 replace indexes with enums > more clear
            callDialog->updateCalls(false);
            dialogStack->setCurrentIndex(1);
            ui->btn_back->setEnabled(true);
        }
```

the CallDialog class looks like this

```
    #include <QDialog>
    #include <QString>
    #include <QList>
    #include <QSound>
    #include <QtDebug>
    #include <QStringList>
    #include <QPushButton>
    #include <QStackedWidget>
    #include <QtAlgorithms>
    #include <QLabel>
    #include <typeinfo>

    #include "ui_calldialog.h"
    #include "callbutton.h"
    #include "categorydialog_new.h"
    #include "../settings/consts.h"
    #include "../webservice/dataconnector.h"
    #include "../webservice/dataconngetter.h"
    #include "../settings/programsettings.h"
    #include "../webservice/pollingservice.h"

    class PollingService;

    namespace Ui {
        class CallDialog;
    }

    class CallDialog : public QDialog
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        //    explicit CallDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
        //    ~CallDialog();
        //    void initCalls();
        //    void updateCalls(bool sound);
        //    void enablePoller();

        explicit CallDialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::CallDialog)
        {
            ui->setupUi(this);
            installEventFilter(this);
```

notice the correct include in the CategoryDialog

they do include each others (maybe cyclic dependency problem?)
I tried with forward declaring CallDialog. didn't help.

the files are only the .h files with implementation directly inside

**EDIT**

I bypassed the problem as follows:
i added an abstract class with the function that CallDialog used from CategoryDialog

like this:

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTDIALOG_H
#define ABSTRACTDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

#include "../objects/call.h"

class AbstractDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AbstractDialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent){}
    void setCall(Call* call){
        _call = call;
    }
private:
    Call* _call;

};

#endif // ABSTRACTDIALOG_H
```

Comment: could you indicate line number and file that caused the compiler error?

Comment: yes, i added the errorline (5th last line in the first code block)

Comment: Could you change the failing line to `((CallDialog*)dialogStack->widget(1))->updateCalls(false);` The `callDialog` variable is used only once on the following line and compiler error complains about `callDialog`, not `CallDialog`. Curious to see what error is produced after the change as I do not see anything obviously wrong with the code.

Comment: Is there a semicolon after the closing brace of the declaration of class CallDialog (there should be one) ?

Comment: @hmjd there are multiple errors: one for callDialog, but several for CallDialog. I tried what you suggested, but still the same errors.

Comment: @AndreHolzner yes the semicolon is there. could have been the problem :D, but it's not :(

Comment: @Berty could you upload all the error that the compiler produces and complete the sources if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaring CallDialog before `CategoryDialog` won't work since `CallDialog` member functions are used and the compiler needs to know about them.

Did you try forward declaring `CategoryDialog` in before `CallDialog` and remove, I'm guessing, `#include "categorydialog_new.h"`?  Since the all of `calldialog.h` is not shown, I'm not sure how you are using `CategoryDialog` in that file.

Comment: i tried, but then it sais it doesn't know CategoryDialog. I'm triing to work around the cyclic include.

Comment: @Berty Since both headers need to use the other, to get around this I believe you are going to have to put the implementations into a cpp files.

Comment: haha, I'm trying to get rid of the cpp files. It slows down the development to much. Unfortunately it creates some of these errors.